# Best practice to share code cross platform

Tags: entity-framework, architecture, xamarin, cross-platform, n-tier-architecture

I'm working on a N-Tier architecture to share as much code as possible on iOS, Android and C# ASP.NET MVC projects.

I've already seperated my solution in several layers:

- Interfaces
- DAL (Entity Framework 6 Model/Db first)
- BLL
- Presentation

I've already seperated my BLL from my DAL, so the BLL is not aware of the DAL. It is injected by the PL. That's because i would like to share my BLL, as it will be the same over several platforms. The downside of this injection is that my PL needs a reference to my DAL. Which in this case might be required, as iOS and Andriod do not support EF to a local db, at least not that i'm aware of.

I'm not sure of going the right way on this. An alternative would be to create some webservices which reference my BLL. The downside of this solution is that an internetconnection is required. Id rather not have that as a requirement in this project.

At the moment I'm doubting whether I'll go left or right. Does anyone have any tips or knows some good articles on this subject?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're injecting dependencies manually rather than using an IoC container, which is why the presentation layer needs to pass a reference to the DAL when it calls the BLL.

Register your types in an IoC container and use it to instantiate the BLL and it will automatically inject the references to the DAL. That way, only the bootstrap code that sets up the IoC container will need to know the specific types.

You have plenty of options regarding the specific IoC container that you use. I recently integrated a wealth of existing code into a mobile app that was using Unity, to good effect.